# How delete extra spaces in Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, jruby, kibana

I have this [log](http://wklej.org/id/2777671/).

How to delete all extra spaces by Logstash? Because this [filter](http://wklej.org/id/2777674/) does not work.

Comment: Refer this https://discuss.elastic.co/t/remove-extra-spaces-between-log-messages-using-mutate-gsub/33031

Comment: but i dont understand that, i just want to delete all where is more than 1 space, how do that?

Comment: ok i think this is harder problem, because if i try to delete all spaces, this dont work. This not should look like this http://wklej.org/id/2777678/. each log starts with date. Any help with this log?

Comment: this help me codec => multiline {  
      pattern => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
      negate => "true"
      what => "next"
      charset => "Windows-1250"
    } But if anyone can help how delete extra spaces i will be greatful.